# MVC and secure CRON jobs

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cron

I have a PHP application that follows a homegrown MVC design.  I'd like to use my Controller to handle CRON jobs as well.  However, I'd also like my CRON jobs to be secure.  Would a viable method to secure the CRON job against malicious public use be to pass a parameter to the method in my Controller, which is inside the webroot, to check against a CRON_PASSWORD that's kept in a config.php file that's outside of my webroot?

For example, if the CRON job calls:

```
my_domain.com/back-up-database/$password
```

then I could just check that CRON_PASSWORD was correct:

```
    public function backUpDatabase($password){
    if ($password !== CRON_PASSWORD) {
         return false;
    } else {
        //back the thing up
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting a password in the URL is bad security practice as URLs are generally logged, and there are lots of other unwanted potential security side-effects.

If you are calling the script from the host machine it's best to create a CLI service within your MVC application.  This service can only be invoked by running php on the local host's command line.  As such it bypasses your web server which is generally configured for serving web traffic, and it's 100% compatible with Cron because that's also a CLI service.

See an example in Zend's MVC framework: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.console.introduction.html

A second option is to use an authentication method that supports machine-to-machine authentication, because you're really talking about integrating two applications here (your server's cron daemon and your MVC application).  OAuth2 is a good example.

http://oauth.net/2/

Comment: I hadn't thought of using OAuth2 in this manner.  However, I have to wonder if there's not a simpler way to do this?